# Virtual Hosts with Laravel and Apache, cannot set ip to website name

Tags: laravel, apache

I want to set the ip for my website to an alphabetized name (i.e. http://54.183.131.205 to http://www.rblog.com). Although I have configured my rblog.com.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available, enabled it and reloaded my apache server, and then adding to my /etc/hosts file 54.183.131.205  www.rblog.com (a tab between the ip and website name), typing in www.rblog.com into my browser doesn't redirect me to my index.php file. However, note that when I type in the ip address in the browser it takes me to my index.php file (I believe this means my rblog.com.conf file is correct?).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@rblog.com
    ServerName www.rblog.com
    ServerAlias www.rblog.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rblog/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/rblog/public>
       Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: change ServerName rblog.com

Comment: @Sahil I did. It still does not work. I also did everything recommended below, but it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@rblog.com
    ServerName rblog.com
    ServerAlias www.rblog.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rblog/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

We can use the a2ensite tool to enable each of our sites like this:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo a2ensite test.com.conf
```

When you are finished, you need to restart Apache to make these changes take effect:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

/etc/hosts file

```
54.183.131.205 rblog.com
```

Comment: I did all of the changes. still does not work. when I type in http://www.rblog.com, it takes me to dnsrsearch.com (to indicate that the site couldn't be found). Some more details on my setup, I am trying to host my website through aws e2c instance, so all of this is on that.

Comment: Maybe, the cache in your pc? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: If you use windows, I will reccomend to use laragon. Its like wamp or xamp but much better and easier.